# jQueryUI Autocomplete won't close on select

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I'm pretty new to jQuery and UI, and I'm having two issue with the autocomplete, and I suspect they're related.  When I select an item in the list, the value, not the label, is displayed in the input.  Second, the autocomplete will not close.  When I step through my code, the select function gets called, and I see my label, not the value, displayed in the input, as I want.  Unfortunately, the close function gets called (twice), and the ui.item.value replaces the label in the input and the autocomplete doesn't close.

My autocomplete code, along with the input HTML, is below.  If it matters, the autocomplete is nested in a jQueryUI dialog.

HTML:

```
<input id="id_projectid" type="text" class="projEntryControl ui-autocomplete-input ui-corner-all" name="projectid" autocomplete="off"></input>
```

AutoComplete:

```
    $('#id_projectid').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/chargeback/projList/" + $('#id_departmentid').val(),
                dataType:"json",
                data: {
                    project_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.projectName,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id_projectid').val(ui.item.label);
        },
        open: function() {
            $( '#id_projectid' ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
```

EDIT:  Adding more code as requested.

Here's the javascript that sets up the dialog, and connects the buttons to open the dialog

```
function setupProjectEntryDialog() {
$( "#addPEForm" ).dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    height: 490,
    width: 376,
    modal: true,
    buttons: {
        "Save": function() {
            var bValid = true;
            allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp( hrsWorked, /^(?!\d{3})(?![2-9]\d)(?!1[1-9])(10|[1-9]{1})(.\d{0,2})?$/, "Please enter a valid number of hours worked." );

            if ( bValid ) {
                //save the changes to the database
                var dataArray = $("#peUpdateForm").serializeArray();
                var ed = new Object();
                ed.name = "entryDateId";
                ed.value = $("#entryDateId").text();
                dataArray.push(ed);
                if ($("#projEntryId").val() != "") {
                    var pe = new Object();
                    pe.name = "projEntryId";
                    pe.value = $("#projEntryId").val();
                    dataArray.push(pe);
                }
                $.post('/chargeback/savepe/', dataArray, function(data){
                    alert(data.msg);

                    //reload the project entries and total hours worked
                    showProjectEntries($('.entryDate.selected'));
                    getTotalHoursForEntryDate($('.entryDate.selected'));
                }, "json");


                //close the window
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                $('#id_projectid').autocomplete("destroy");
            }
        },
        Cancel: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
            $('#id_projectid').autocomplete("destroy");
        }
    },
    close: function() {
        allFields.val( "" ).removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
    }
});

//connect the add new button
$("#addNewPEButton").click(function() {
    $( "#addPEForm" ).dialog( "open" );
});

//hook up the add new project entry form submittal
$("#addNewPE").submit(function() {
    addProjectEntry($(this));
    return false;
});

//connect the delete Project Entry button
$('#deletePEButton').click(function() {
    deleteProjectEntry($('.peRow.selected'));
    return false;
});

//connect the row click method to the function
$('.peRow').click(function() {
    peRowWasClicked($(this));
});

$('.peRow').dblclick(function() {
    peRowWasDoubleClicked($(this));
})
}
```

Here's the javascript that loads the Dialog using a Django form and template to generate the HTML.

```
function addProjectEntry(anED) {
//ensure all peRows are not selected and disable the delete project entry button
$('.peRow').removeClass('selected');
$('#deletePEButton').attr('disabled', true);

//disable newFavoriteFromPEButton
$('#newFavoriteFromPEButton').attr('disabled', true);

//get the id of the selected entry date and strip the ed_ from it
$selectedED = $(".entryDate.selected");
var edId = $selectedED[0].id.split("_");    
$("#addPEForm").load("/chargeback/cb_timeentry/newPE/" + edId[1], function() {
    //connect the variables to the newly loaded html
    connectDialogVariables();

    //connect the project filtering to the department change
    /*$("#id_departmentid").change(function() {
        getProjectsForDepartment();
    });*/

    //connect the project and program number autocompletes to the controls
    $('#id_projectid').autocomplete({
        source: function(request, response) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/chargeback/projList/" + $('#id_departmentid').val(),
                dataType:"json",
                data: {
                    project_startsWith: request.term
                },
                success: function(data) {
                    response( $.map( data.results, function( item ) {
                        return {
                            label: item.projectName,
                            value: item.id
                        }
                    }));
                }
            });
        },
        minLength: 3,
        select: function(event, ui) {
            $('#id_projectid').val(ui.item.label);
            $(this).close();
            return false;
        },
        open: function() {
            $( '#id_projectid' ).removeClass( "ui-corner-all" ).addClass( "ui-corner-top" );
        },
        close: function() {
            $( this ).removeClass( "ui-corner-top" ).addClass( "ui-corner-all" );
        }
    });
});
}
```

This is the HTML after the ajax call completes, and the above javascript completes.  The autocomplete begins the search when typing in the correct text input, and is positioned correctly, but isn't part of the form.

```
<div class="ui-dialog ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all ui-draggable ui-resizable ui-dialog-buttons" style="outline: 0px none; z-index: 1002; position: absolute; height: auto; width: 376px; top: 66px; left: 297.5px; display: block;" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-9">
<div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-widget-header ui-corner-all ui-helper-clearfix">
<span id="ui-id-9" class="ui-dialog-title">Project Entry Update</span>
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button">
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
</a>
</div>
    <div id="addPEForm" class="ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content" style="width: auto; min-height: 0px; height: 367px;" scrolltop="0" scrollleft="0"><form action="" id="peUpdateForm" method="post">
<div style="display:none"><input type="hidden" value="BTrLZBVfA2ltExq3OUU5015BVxPKO9lL" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"></div>
<p><label for="id_departmentid">Department:</label> 
<select name="departmentid" class="projEntryControl" id="id_departmentid">
    <option selected="selected" value="">Choose a Department</option>
    <option value="1">ABND</option>
    <option value="2">ATT</option>
    <option value="3">AVI</option>
    <option value="4">CCS</option>
    <option value="5">PBW</option>
</select></p>
<p>
    <label for="id_projectid">Project:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="projectid" class="projEntryControl ui-autocomplete-input" id="id_projectid" autocomplete="off">
    <span role="status" aria-live="polite" class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible"></span>
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_progNumId">Program Number:</label> 
    <input type="text" name="progNumId" class="projEntryControl" id="id_progNumId">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_hoursWorked">Hours Worked:</label>
    <input type="text" id="id_hoursWorked" maxlength="5" class="projEntryControl" value="0.0" name="hoursWorked">
</p>
<p>
    <label for="id_notes">Notes:</label>
    <textarea name="notes" cols="40" rows="10" id="id_notes"></textarea
</p>
<p style="display:none;" id="entryDateId">1</p>
<p style="display:none;" id="projEntryId"></p>
</form>
</div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se ui-icon-grip-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 1000;">
</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 1000;"></div>
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonpane ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix">
<div class="ui-dialog-buttonset">
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Save</span>
    </button>
    <button type="button" class="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
        <span class="ui-button-text">Cancel</span>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="width: 979px; height: 567px; z-index: 1001;"></div>
<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-11" tabindex="0" style="z-index: 1003; display: none;">
</ul>
```

Comment: Do you see any errors? It's weird that the menu won't close. Do you see the problem here? http://jsfiddle.net/J5rVP/21/ (I know how to fix the `label`/`value` problem but I'm curious about the menu not closing)

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker No error in the console.  I do not have the problem in your jsfiddle example; that works as expected.

Comment: Interesting. I'll try it in a dialog to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I should add that the jsfiddle also doesn't show the label.  It shows the value, though you may not have intended to fix that in your quick example.  Thanks regardless

Comment: Not happening in a dialog either... weird. Do you have any other code on the page that's manipulating the widget in any way?

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Not that I can find.  I did have some code that got called to update a select (that's the control I was using originally), but I commented all that out and ran it, and same result, so I'm pretty sure this is all there is.

Comment: Well to fix the `select` problem, use `event.preventDefault` or `return false` from the handler (in addition to the code you already have). Maybe they are related.

Comment: Thanks on the select problem.  Returning false solved that.  Unfortunately, it didn't hide the autocomplete.  I'm afraid this might turn into a really difficult one.

Comment: @AndrewWhitaker Even more strange is that even when I close the dialog, the autocomplete will not close.  The control stays visible on the main page, and I can hover and get the css changes expected on hover.  It's as if it's not connected to the dialog in some weird way!  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Can you show all of your code, including the dialog initialization, opening, and closing?

Comment: I'll try.  The dialog load is from an Ajax call using a Django template.

Comment: I experienced some inconsistency with autocomplete as well particularly on slower devices, especially when a prompt is shown on select or when the input is blurred on select. My issue was that a second search is launched after the box is closed, which will re-open the box. I wrapped the stuff I did in `select` with a setTimeout (0 delay) to force it to execute after the stack is cleared and that seems to have helped me, without returning false or preventing event default. Maybe you can try it?